# Existence of sufficient statistic collapsing *sets* of sample points with identical likelihood functions

Tags: probability-theory, statistics

Suppose $\Omega$ is a finite set and $\{P_{\theta}\}_{\theta \in \Theta}$ is a family of measures defined on the power set algebra of $\Omega$.  Suppose $E, F \subseteq \Omega$ are subsets for which there is a positive constant $c > 0$ such that $P_{\theta}(E) = c \cdot P_{\theta}(F)$ for all $\theta \in \Theta$.  Does there exist a sufficient statistic $T$ such that $T[E]=T[F]$? Here, $T[S] := \{T(\omega): \omega \in \Omega \}$ is the range of $S$ under $T$, and recall, a statistic is sufficient if $P_{\theta}(\omega|T=T(\omega))=P_{\eta}(\omega|T=T(\omega))$ for all $\theta, \eta \in \Theta$, i.e., if $P_{\theta}(\omega|T=T(\omega))$ is not a function of $\theta$.

The answer is "yes'' when $E$ and $F$ are singletons $\{\omega_E\}$ and $\{\omega_F\}$ respectively, as then one can define $T(\omega)$ to be equal to the likelihood function of $\omega$ if $\omega \not \in \{\omega_E, \omega_F \}$ and equal to some arbitrary value (say $1$) otherwise.  My question is whether this construction can be generalized in some obvious way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've realized the answer to this question is "no."  Let $\Omega = \{1,2,3\}$, $\Theta=\{\theta_1, \theta_2\}$.  Suppose the probability measures $P_{\theta_i}:=P_i$ re defined as follows for $i=1,2$:

- $P_i(1) = 1/2$ if $i=1$ and $1/6$ if $i=2$,
- $P_i(2)= 1/6$ if $i=1$ and $1/2$ if $i=2$,
- $P_i(3) = 1/3$ for $i=1,2$.

Let $E=\{3\}$ and $F=\{1,2\}$ and $c=1/2 > 0$.  Then $P_i(E) = c \cdot P_i(F)$ for $i=1,2$.  But there is no sufficient statistic $T$ such that $T[E]=T[F]$.  For if $T[F] = T[E]$, then the range of $T$ is a singleton $\{t\}$.  And if $T(1)=T(2)=T(3) = t$, it follows that $P_i(\omega|T=t) = P_i(\omega)$.  And clearly $P_{i}(\omega)$ depends upon $i$ in general (e.g., $\omega \in \{1,2\}$).